# conditionally rendered elements that use ref

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ref

I have a component that renders a child `<ul/>` conditionally based on if data is fetched from the backend.

```
class groupInfo extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.setSubGroupRef = this.setSubGroupRef.bind(this);
        this.checkSubgroupOverflow = this.checkSubgroupOverflow.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            data: null,
            overflowingSubgroups: false,
        }
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        //fetch data from backend
        this.setState({data})
    }
    setSubGroupRef(node){
        this.subGroupRef = node;
        node.addEventListener("resize", this.checkSubgroupOverflow);
    }
    componentWillUnmount() {
        if (this.subGroupRef) {
            this.subGroupRef.removeEventListener("resize", this.checkSubgroupOverflow);
        }
    }
    checkSubgroupOverflow() {
        const element = this.subGroupContainer;
        if (element) {
            // Check against baseline rendered height of our subgroup container, plus a few safe pixels.
            // Magic number here because we know what the height *should* be when its collapsed by CSS.
            this.setState({
                overflowingSubgroups: (element.scrollHeight > 36),
            });
        }
    }
    render() {
        const {overflowingSubgroups, data} = this.state
        return (
            <div>
                <div>
                    some information
                </div>
                {
                    data.type === "group" ?
                    <div ref={this.setSubGroupRef}>
                        <ul>
                            {
                                data.subGroups.map((subData) => {
                                    return (
                                        <li>
                                            // display sub-data info
                                        </li>
                                    )
                                })
                            }
                        </ul>
                        {
                            overflowingSubgroups ?
                                <span
                                    className="iconMore"
                                    onClick={this.toggleSubgroupExpansion}
                                >
                                    <img
                                        src={`${iconPath}icon-arrow.svg`}
                                        alt="more"
                                    />
                                </span> :
                            null
                        }
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

What i'm trying to achieve here is if the `<ul/>` is over flowing id like to add a toggle switch based on if my containing div is overflowing or not.
The issue is that as i'm navigating between these subGroups for the first time it also re-renders `groupInfo` causing a re-fetch of the data that is then stored in the redux store for later use but this also causes a new node instance to be spawned and I'm unable to kill my old eventListener. Now `componentWillUnmount` is not called since the component is just being re-rendered with new data.

Im trying to avoid creating a child React component for the `<ul/>` based on the data.type since this will involve a major refactor.